# Proper way to save image from front end app to backend API

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

In my case I'm using AngularJS and Django backend with Django Rest framework. So I need to save a Profile data with image. My model in database looks like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    avatar = models.ImageField()
```

But I can't decide what a best way to save this image on front end.

**Solution 1 - Convert image to base64 and create `Base64Serializer` in Django:**

https://xploit29.com/2016/09/13/upload-files-to-django-rest-framework-using-angularjs/

For me the most easy way

**Solution 2 - Multipart/form-data File Upload with AngularJS**

https://withintent.uncorkedstudios.com/multipart-form-data-file-upload-with-angularjs-c23bf6eeb298

I don't like the things like:

```
$http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} 
})
```

Looks like hack. And the same on backend side. We need to use https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser

**Solution 3 - Create a separate view to upload files and change database to**:

```
class Image(models.Model):
   image = models.ImageField()

class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    avatar = models.ForeignKey('Image', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=NULL)
```

It is complicate to use on existing database, but seems very flexible. But also using **solution 2** to implement file upload

Comment: Posting base64 data is inefficient for bandwidth and memory. The most efficient is to POST using a [Blob object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

Comment: Other way you can try, maybe simple to change upload this image to s3, save only link image return from s3 in database.